# dict zip key values django template

Tags: django, dictionary, zip, keyvaluepair

Pairing of 2 dict values.It works.

```
pair = dict(zip(hide_dict, fp_dict))
    context = {
        'instance': project,
        'user': user,
        'pair': pair,
    }
```

My django html template part,where I am getting error.

> Exception Type:   ValueError Exception Value:  Need 2 values to unpack
>   in for loop; got 6.

Am I done false the for loop part ?   Earlier I tried pairing, I tried separately and it works fine.  Now with pairing it shows that the error is in context rendering,but I can't see where.

```
 {% for fp_dict.items,hide_dict.items in pair %}
    {% for key, values in hide_dict.items %}
            {%if values == 1%}
            <div style="display:none">
                {% elif  values == 0 %}
                <div>
                    {% endif %}{% endfor %}
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>FP Items</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                  <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                {% for key, values in fp_dict.items %}
                                {% for instance in values %}
                                            <td></td>
                                    <td>{{ instance.FP_Item }}</td>
                                                </a>
                                            </td> -->
                                        </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Dict Values in the view before pairing:
print(hide_dict)
{'hide0': 1, 'hide1': 1}

print(fp_dict)

```
{'fp_list_0': <QuerySet [<FP: olmadan çalışacaktır. - Check - OK - Check - Check - OK - Check - Check - Check>, <FP: depolanabilecek. - Check - OK - Check - Check - OK - Check - Check - Check>, <FP: yönetilebilecektir. - Check - OK - Check - Check - OK - Check - Check
- Check>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>}
```

Comment: I think that first line should have the `.items` removed from it. So: `{% for fp_dict, hide_dict in pair %}` because that's a variable declaration, not a space for getting attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to iterating over pair items, so you need to use `pair.items`:

```
{% for fp_dict, hide_dict in pair.items %}
```

Comment: yes that fix the error but I couldn't get any values in my table let me check further

Comment: Is second line correct ? {% for key, values in hide_dict.items %} with items at the end.Without it I tried and got error

Comment: @ahmet you cannot do `hide_dict.items` since `hide_dict` and `fp_dict` is not actually a dictionary. After this line of code `pair = dict(zip(hide_dict, fp_dict))` pair is simpe dict. So it's items is not dictionaries itselfs.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the items and now getting another error.  Exception Type: ValueError Exception Value:Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.  Should I also need to change  to {% for values in hide_dict %}  so need to delete key in front as I am only using values, but nothing changed

Comment: @ahmet `hide_dict` event may not be iterable. Can you share what values have `hide_dict` and `fp_dict` in view. And what value you want `pair` to be?

Comment: I added to the question the outputs in the view.py, number of elements in bot is different should I also need to do zip longest ?

Comment: @ahmet what do you expect as `pair` value?

Comment: On each change of items within the fplist. I want to go to top and rebuild the tables that's my main issue.